# Robocopy command is not copying files and folders

Tags: windows, powershell, robocopy

Im attempting the simplest use of robocopy with powershell:

```
robocopy C:\Users\tkeen\Documents\test\ C:\Users\tkeen\Documents\test2\
```

It doesn't seem to do anything. This is the response I get back:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   ROBOCOPY     ::     Robust File Copy for Windows
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  Started : Friday, April 22, 2022 5:51:41 PM
   Source : C:\Users\tkeen\Documents\test\
     Dest : C:\Users\tkeen\Documents\test2\

    Files : *.*

  Options : *.* /DCOPY:DA /COPY:DAT /R:1000000 /W:30

------------------------------------------------------------------------------

                           0    C:\Users\tkeen\Documents\test\

------------------------------------------------------------------------------

               Total    Copied   Skipped  Mismatch    FAILED    Extras
    Dirs :         1         0         1         0         0         0
   Files :         0         0         0         0         0         0
   Bytes :         0         0         0         0         0         0
   Times :   0:00:00   0:00:00                       0:00:00   0:00:00
   Ended : Friday, April 22, 2022 5:51:41 PM
```

I tried with other options like \MIR but then I just get a "ERROR : Invalid Parameter #3 : \mir" message. Not sure what Im doing wrong.

Comment: Are you attempting to copy just the root of the folder? Otherwise, you have to specify to copy the subdirectories as well: `robocopy "C:\Users\tkeen\Documents\test\" "C:\Users\tkeen\Documents\test2\" /e`. Take note of `/e`, it's a forward slash and will not take a blackslash. That is why `\MIR` didn't work as it should be `/MIR` (*`/MIR` will also assume the flag of `/Purge` so I'd read into what you want first*). It's also best practice to quote the paths. Run `Robocopy.exe /?` to get more help from it. `/e` will copy subdirectories including empty ones.

Comment: as AbrahamZinala hinted, the `robocopy` util is _directory oriented_. it does not start out "thinking" about files ... it starts with directories. it also sees ONLY the one you list ... unless you tell it to look down the tree. ///// also, in powershell, you can use a variant of splatting to build the parameter list and pass it to the `robocopy` call. here is an example ... >>> Robocopy_-_Demo_and_FullParameterList - Pastebin.com — https://pastebin.com/EVuWrVa2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Below

```
robocopy "Source" "destination" /MIR /E /XO /xx /tee /R:2 /W:1 /SEC /LOG:"o/p path"
```

MIR - mirrors directory - deletes files which is present in destination but not in source
E - copies subdirectories even folder is empty
X0 - excludes older files - we can say for incremental
xx - excludes extra files - will not delete extra files in destination (XX overtakes MIR)
tee - gives output in command prompt also
R - Number of Retries on failure
W - Wait time between Retries
SEC - copy with security
LOG - output path

Comment: try removing \ at end, C:\Users\tkeen\Documents\test